# Why change nominative case?

Tags: nominative

I’m learning about German cases and this specifically regards the nominative case, but I don’t understand why you make the change for example from “ Das ist der Baum” to “Das ist ein Baum”. Why can’t it stay “der Baum”, why do you have to change it to “ein Baum”?

Comment: Do you know about the difference between [definite and indefinite articles](https://www.dictionary.com/e/definite-vs-indefinite-articles/)? This is not a German specific matter.

Comment: It also has nothing to do with cases.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple:

> 1. Das ist **der** Baum = This is **the** tree.
> 2. Das ist **ein** Baum = This is **a** tree.

In 1 you are talking about a specific tree (maybe the big chestnut tree right in your grandpa's garden.)

In 2 you are talking abut just any tree.

Btw. in both sentences *der Baum* and *ein Baum* are in nominative case. It's not the case that is different, it is the [definiteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness).

- definite: (a specific tree)

  - Nominativ: Das ist **der Baum.**
  - Genitiv: Der Gärtner nahm sich **des Baumes** an. Das Laub **des Baumes** ist grün. (Also allowed: *des Baums*)
  - Dativ: Das heiße Wetter schadet **dem Baum.**
  - Akkusativ: Ich sehe **den Baum.**
- indefinite: (just any tree)

  - Nominativ: Das ist **ein Baum.**
  - Genitiv: Der Gärtner nahm sich **eines Baumes** an. Das Laub **eines Baumes** ist grün.
  - Dativ: Das heiße Wetter schadet **einem Baum.**
  - Akkusativ: Ich sehe **einen Baum.**

Translations:

> Nominative: This is the/a tree.
> Genitive: The gardener took care of the/a tree. The leaves of the/a tree are green.
> Dative: The hot weather damages the/a tree.
> Accusative: I see the/a tree.